# Redirecting wget output

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to output all content from this

```bash
wget --spider -S $URL
```

to a .txt file. I tried `2>&1 >inst/logfile.log` and `--output-file=wgetlog.txt`

Comment: 1) which URL 2) use **MORE QUOTES** : `"$url"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this `--spider` switch.

You only need:

```
# urls array
urls=( 'https://example.org' 'https://dk' 'https://nic.fr' )
wget "${urls[@]}"
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: Thank you for the answer , its for a list of $URL's. sorry should have mentioned it